# Good ol' fashion Clickbait

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> Look at me!
>
> Funny, Sad or Bold;
>
> I'm just like clickbait, but range from times that are old.
>
> You may see me while travelling, surfing, watching, and sometimes you
>   won't even know I'm there!
>
> If you don't then I can really make you care.
>
> When associated with some, leaves me often banned.
>
> Although I may seem random I'm carefully planned.

What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> An advertisement?

Look at me!

> Ads are designed to be looked at

Funny, Sad or Bold;

> A possible way to categorize ad content.

I'm just like clickbait, but range from times that are old.

> Clickbait titles are a form of Ad, ads are designed to draw attention more than be accurate.

You may see me while travelling, surfing, watching, and sometimes you won't even know I'm there!

> Travelling: Billboards, surfing(the web): banner ads, Watching: Tv Commercials, Don't notice: Subliminal Ads

If you don't then I can really make you care.

> There are thoughts that Subliminal advertisements are more effective than their blatant counterparts

When associated with some, leaves me often banned.

> This could be "some leaves" which would specifically target Tobacco, or it could just be a reference to how certain things aren't allowed to be advertised.

Although I may seem random I'm carefully planned.

> Some ads don't appear to make much sense on the face, but pretty much all are the result of much time spent by a marketing department.

Comment: Well done! Great answer!